# Widget Update problems using a for loop

Tags: php, widgets

I try to develop a widget which enabels the functionality of creating tables. It is important that the user can determine how many columns and lines he wants. I already managed to generate a user-specific amount of input fields in the backend. My problem is that I am not able to save the content from the input fields. For that I am using a for-loop within the update method.

I hope someone can guide me into the right direction.

Tank you very much!

My Code:

```
class table_widget extends WP_Widget {

function __construct() {
$widget_ops = array(
  'classname' => 'table_det_widget',
  'description' => 'Tabelle erstellen',
);
parent:: __construct(false, $name = __('Tabelle'), $widget_ops);
}

function form($instance) { /*Ausgabe im Backend*/

echo '<label for="' . $this->get_field_id('wp_table_title') . '">Überschrift: </label>';
echo '<input class="widefat" type="text" value="' . $instance['wp_table_title'] .'" name="' . $this->get_field_name('wp_table_title') . '" id="' . $this->get_field_id('wp_table_title') . '" >';

echo '<label for="' . $this->get_field_id('wp_table_subtitle') . '">Unterüberschrift: </label>';
echo '<input class="widefat" type="text" value="' . $instance['wp_table_subtitle'] .'" name="' . $this->get_field_name('wp_table_subtitle') . '" id="' . $this->get_field_id('wp_table_subtitle') . '" >';

echo '<label for="' . $this->get_field_id('wp_column') . '">Spalten: </label>';
echo '<input class="widefat" type="text" value="' . $instance['wp_column'] .'" name="' . $this->get_field_name('wp_column') . '" id="' . $this->get_field_id('wp_column') . '" >';

echo '<label for="' . $this->get_field_id('wp_line') . '">Zeilen pro Spalte: </label>';
echo '<input class="widefat" type="text" value="' . $instance['wp_line'] .'" name="' . $this->get_field_name('wp_line') . '" id="' . $this->get_field_id('wp_line') . '" >';

if($instance['wp_column'] == '' || $instance['wp_line'] == '') {
    echo 'Bitte beide Felder ausfüllen!';
} else {
    $spalten = $instance['wp_column'];
    $zeilen = $instance['wp_line'];

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $zeilen; $i++) {
        echo "<label style='display: block; margin-top: 10px;'>Zeile {$i}</label>";

        for ($j = 1; $j <= $spalten; $j++) {
            $instSpecLine = $instance["spec_line_{$i}_{$j}"];
            echo "<input class='widefat' type='text' value='{$instSpecLine}' name='{$instSpecLine}' id='{$instSpecLine}' placeholder='Spalte {$j}' >";
        }

        $j = 0;
    }
}
}

function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
$instance = $old_instance;

$instance['wp_table_title'] = $new_instance['wp_table_title'];
$instance['wp_table_subtitle'] = $new_instance['wp_table_subtitle'];

$instance['wp_line'] = $new_instance['wp_line'];
$instance['wp_column'] = $new_instance['wp_column'];

$spalten = $instance['wp_column'];
$zeilen = $instance['wp_line'];

for ($i = 1; $i <= $zeilen; $i++) {
    for ($j = 1; $j <= $spalten; $j++) {

        $instSpecLine = "spec_line_{$i}_{$j}";

        $instance[$instSpecLine] = $new_instance[$instSpecLine];

    }
}   

return $instance;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace below line:

```
echo "<input class='widefat' type='text' value='{$instSpecLine}' name='{$instSpecLine}' id='{$instSpecLine}' placeholder='Spalte {$j}' >";
```

With Below code:

```
echo "<input class='widefat' type='text' value='{$instSpecLine}' name='".$this->get_field_name("spec_line_{$i}_{$j}")."' id='{$instSpecLine}' placeholder='Spalte {$j}' >";
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer! Can't believe I made this mistake...works like a charm now!